# How do I link libraries statically with gcc?

Tags: gcc, static-linking

I am new to C++ compiling/linking.

I am trying to link all libraries statically with gcc, I tried using LDFLAGS=-static but did not work. Error message showed:

> /bin/sh ./libtool  --tag=CXX   --mode=link /home/dizhang/lib/hdf5/bin/h5c++  -g -O2 -L/home/dizhang/lib/blitz/lib -L/home/dizhang/lib/libconfig/lib  -o angora  src/libangora.la -lblitz -lconfig++
>   libtool: link: /home/dizhang/lib/hdf5/bin/h5c++ -g -O2 -o angora  -L/home/dizhang/lib/blitz/lib -L/home/dizhang/lib/libconfig/lib src/.libs/libangora.a -L/bgsys/drivers/V1R2M2/ppc64/comm/lib64 -L/bgsys/drivers/V1R2M2/ppc64/comm/lib -L/bgsys/drivers/V1R2M2/ppc64/spi/lib -lpthread -lm /home/dizhang/lib/blitz/lib/libblitz.a /bgsys/drivers/V1R2M2/ppc64/comm/lib/libmpichcxx-gcc.so /bgsys/drivers/toolchain/V1R2M2_base/gnu-linux/powerpc64-bgq-linux/lib/libstdc++.so /bgsys/drivers/V1R2M2/ppc64/comm/lib/libmpich-gcc.so /bgsys/drivers/V1R2M2/ppc64/comm/lib/libopa-gcc.so /bgsys/drivers/V1R2M2/ppc64/comm/lib/libmpl-gcc.so /home/dizhang/lib/libconfig/lib/libconfig++.a /bgsys/drivers/toolchain/V1R2M2_base-efix014/gnu-linux/powerpc64-bgq-linux/lib/libstdc++.so -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/bgsys/drivers/toolchain/V1R2M2_base-efix014/gnu-linux/powerpc64-bgq-linux/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/bgsys/drivers/V1R2M2/ppc64/comm/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/bgsys/drivers/toolchain/V1R2M2_base/gnu-linux/powerpc64-bgq-linux/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/bgsys/drivers/toolchain/V1R2M2_base-efix014/gnu-linux/powerpc64-bgq-linux/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/bgsys/drivers/V1R2M2/ppc64/comm/lib -Wl,-rpath -Wl,/bgsys/drivers/toolchain/V1R2M2_base/gnu-linux/powerpc64-bgq-linux/lib
>   /bgsys/drivers/toolchain/V1R2M2_base-efix014/gnu-linux/lib/gcc/powerpc64-bgq-linux/4.4.7/../../../../powerpc64-bgq-linux/bin/ld: **attempted static link of dynamic object** `/bgsys/drivers/V1R2M2/ppc64/comm/lib/libmpichcxx-gcc.so'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I did some search and found that, telling Makefile `-Wl -Bstatic` may solve this problem, but how exactly I should change this in my Makefile?

I tried searching -Wl in Makefile but it was not in the text.

Thanks,

Di

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to build HDF5 with MPI support on BGQ.

As long as you end up passing a ".so" version of a lib to gcc on BGQ -- you will see this error. You may need to check how you are passing MPI info to HDF5's configure script.

In my case (building another project that uses CMake) passing BGQ's MPI compiler wrappers to CMake always created a problem where it would try to link MPI using the shared libs instead of the static ones. To resolve this, I had to make sure to explicitly specify the ".a" variants of the MPI libs.